# Record cannot be deleted

Tags: android

I have a Adapter class in which I have made a method to delete a record from the table.
In my table there are only three fields: id, status(bool) and num. In this case when I try to delete a record with fire query with id than I achieve the deleting like:

```
public boolean deleteContact(long rowID){
  return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID, null) > 0;
}
```

But I want to delete record by number which is sqlite text data typeed:

```
public void deleteFromNum(String num){
  db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NUM + "=" + "740-514-8806", null);
}
```

Above method does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: What error are you getting? How did you trying fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings should be enclosed in `''`

```
public void deleteFromNum(String num){
  db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NUM + "='" + "740-514-8806" + "'", null);
}
```

Comment: public void deleteFromNum(String num){
  db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NUM + "=" + "'740-514-8806'", null);
}                                                                     yes ya..i understand i got it thanks Alex..........